# Getting the ProductDetails price in android-billing-5.0

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have upgraded my Kotlin app to android-billing 5.0 from 4.0, and as such, SkuDetails is now deprecated so I am migrating to using ProductDetails using the [migration instructions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5).

Previously I displayed the purchase price for in-app purchases to the user using [SkuDetails.price](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails#getPrice()), but I cannot find a similar method in [ProductDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails).

In Google Play Billing Library 5.0, is there a non-deprecated way to retrieve the price for an in-app purchase or subscription?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails) you can call `getOneTimePurchaseOfferDetails()` on ProductDetails to return a [`ProductDetails.OneTimePurchaseOfferDetails`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.OneTimePurchaseOfferDetails) object, which has a `getFormattedPrice()` method to return the price for in-app purchases.

For subscriptions you can call `getSubscriptionOfferDetails()` which returns a list of [`ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails) objects, which have a `getPricingPhases()` method to return different pricing phases. The [pricing phase](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.PricingPhase) objects have a `getFormattedPrice()` method to get the price from.

**UPDATE**

To better explain what this new approach allows, you can now create multiple "base plans" for a given subscription product. For example, you could create an "unlimited" product, then create an "unlimited-annual" plan for $50/year and an "unlimited-monthly" plan for $5/month.

The `ProductDetails` returned for a configuration like that would look like this - where you have a single `productId` with multiple payment rates/plans. If you add a promotion (e.g. discount for the first year) that shows up with a non-null `offerId` under an existing base plan ID.

```
{
  productId: "unlimited",

  subscriptionOfferDetails: 
  [
    {
      basePlanId: "unlimited-monthly",
      offerId: null,
      pricingPhases:
      [
        {formattedPrice: "$5", billingPeriod: P1M, recurrence: 1}
      ]
    },

    {
      basePlanId: "unlimited-annual",
      offerId: null,
      pricingPhases:
      [
        {formattedPrice: "$50", billingPeriod: P1Y, recurrence: 1}
      ]
    },

    {
      basePlanId: "unlimited-annual",
      offerId: "unlimited-annual-promotion",
      pricingPhases:
      [
        {formattedPrice: "$30", billingPeriod: P1Y, recurrence: 2}
        {formattedPrice: "$50", billingPeriod: P1Y, recurrence: 1}
      ]
    }
  ],
 
  oneTimePurchaseOfferDetails: null
}
```

There are also details from Google [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973) about the new format.

Comment: ... why would they change a perfectly fine & simple method into something so unnecessarily complicated??

Comment: No idea... I need to do this migration myself still but am putting it off for now...

Comment: Read https://qonversion.io/blog/google-play-billing-library-5-0/ to see the idea behind the curtain

Comment: @Big_Chair, no kidding, the API in version 4 was already insanely complicated, and they decided to add a new layer of complexity.

Answer (score 15):

In Kotlin you can call this on the product

```
subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.pricingPhases?.pricingPhaseList?.get(0)?.formattedPrice
```

Comment: It works, But ... OMG I can't believe that's the thing we have to write just to get the price .... !!! ???

Comment: @ekashking it used to be easier, but I guess google didn't think so

Comment: This will fail when the subscription base plan has multiple offers. subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)? -> from what I can see, it is not guaranteed that the base plan is at position 0

Comment: If we look the documentation, I', afraid, this oneliner is the simplest way to handle this, if we have one product with one time period. With many product with many time periods it is even more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

In java you can get the price as a string (complete with the appropriate currency sign) thusly:

```
product.get(i).getOneTimePurchaseOfferDetails().getFormattedPrice()
```

where **product** is a **List<ProductDetails**> from the **onProductDetailsResponse** listener

(I understand the question was for kotlin, but this is one of the first hits you find when search for this solution so a Java answer is worth including as well).