# Google Play Billing v5 - Get a product's price

Tags: in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

In v4, I used to have SkuDetails.price to get the price of the product but now it's not available anymore in the new ProductDetails in v5.

How can I get the price of a product in this new version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the ProductDetails price in android-billing-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235984/getting-the-productdetails-price-in-android-billing-5-0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `getSubscriptionOfferDetails`, it returns the offers available to buy for the subscription product. Then you can call `getPricingPhases()` to get the list of the pricing phases. Each pricing phase object has a `getFormattedPrice()` call to get the price of an offer's pricing phrase (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.PricingPhase)

Comment: Is it only for subscriptions? What about in-app products?

Comment: There's a `OnetimePurchaseOfferDetails` object that has a `getFormattedPrice()` call. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.OneTimePurchaseOfferDetails

Answer (score 3):

You have to check for Available Products

```
fun getAvailableProducts() {
    Timber.d("!!! Getting available products to buy ...")

    val queryProductDetailsParams =
        QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(
                listOf(
                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                        .setProductId(SKU_SUBSCRIBE_MONTHLY)
                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                        .build(),
                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                        .setProductId(SKU_SUBSCRIBE_YEARLY)
                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                        .build()
                ))
            .build()

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) {
            billingResult,
            productDetailsList ->
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            availableProducts.tryEmit(productDetailsList)
            getPrices(productDetailsList)
        } else {
            Timber.d("!!!Error getting available Products to buy: ${billingResult.responseCode} ${billingResult.debugMessage}")
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
    private fun getPrices(productDetailsList: MutableList<ProductDetails>) {
        productDetailsList.forEach{
            when (it.productId) {
                SKU_SUBSCRIBE_MONTHLY -> {
                    currency.tryEmit(it.subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.pricingPhases!!.pricingPhaseList[0]?.priceCurrencyCode.toString())
                    monthlyPrice.tryEmit(it.subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.pricingPhases!!.pricingPhaseList[0]?.formattedPrice.toString())
                    Timber.d("!!!! $it.")
                }
                SKU_SUBSCRIBE_YEARLY -> {
//                    currency.tryEmit(it.subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.pricingPhases!!.pricingPhaseList[0]?.priceCurrencyCode.toString())
                    yearlyPrice.tryEmit(it.subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.pricingPhases!!.pricingPhaseList[0]?.formattedPrice.toString())
                    Timber.d("!!!! $it.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i use the following code to get price details.

private void queryProduct() {

```
    QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams
            = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(
                    ImmutableList.of(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                            .setProductId("your_product_id")
                            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP).build()))
            .build();

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
            queryProductDetailsParams,

            new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProductDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<ProductDetails> list) {
                    if(!list.isEmpty()){

                        productDetails = list.get(0);
                        itemdesc.setText(productDetails.getName());
                        itemprice.setText(productDetails.getOneTimePurchaseOfferDetails().getFormattedPrice());

                        itemprice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                makePurchase();
                            }
                        });

                    }else {

                        Log.i("playsresponse", "no response from google play");
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Please make sure you add explanation to and around your code to make it useful for the OP and future readers as to they *why* you'd do this

Comment: That won't work for Subscriptions prices, only "INAPP" purchases. "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetails$OneTimePurchaseOfferDetails.getFormattedPrice()' on a null object reference"